# Right justify a list of values

Tags: autohotkey

I am an irregular AHK user and typically work at the edge of my knowledge.
I usually need to keep the help files to hand.
I am using Version 1.0.48.05 and have a problem.

In a nutshell - I want to print a list of numeric values using the Gui interface so that the values line up under each other justified to the right.
I can not find an easy or robust way of doing that.  What am I missing.
The values can vary from 0 to 9999.  They are always integers.

====================

This is a snippet of code before I try to right-justify :

```
tabpos := 200
Gui, Add, Text, x%tabpos% y300, %value1%
Gui, Add, Text, x%tabpos% y320, %value2%
Gui, Add, Text, x%tabpos% y340, %value3%
Gui, Add, Text, x%tabpos% y360, %value4%
```

That prints my values at the "tabpos" position but all left-justified.

My first attempt to right-justify was to use a function which padded with a number of spaces determined by the length of the "value" .  For exammple :

```
Gui, Add, Text, x%tabpos% y300, % pad(6, value1)

pad(width, val)
{
   ans :=  SubStr("      ", 1, width-StrLen(val)).val
   return ans
}
```

But that did not work well as the width of a digit was not the same as (or a multiple of) the width of a space.
Where I introduced a multiple into the function, that worked differently for different type sizes and typefaces.

My second attempt was to adjust the "tabpos" by a number of pixels depending on the length of the "value".  For example :

```
newpos := tabpos - 9*StrLen(value1)     ; Where a digit is 9 pixels wide
Gui, Add, Text, x%newpos% y300, %value1%
```

But that only works well where a digit is exactly 9 pixels wide.  I would like a more general, robust method.

I have tried using the AHK SetFormat instruction, but have failed to get any effect.  Perhaps I am using it incorrectly.  In any event, it appears that SetFormat works by padding with spaces and so it would have the same effect as my first attempt (above) with the same problems.

==================

Any suggestions will be very welcome.

I would like the method to work whatever the typeface, type size, whether bold or normal, and whatever the DPI of the monitor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about...

```
Gui, Add, Text, x100 y100 w100 Right, 123
Gui, Add, Text, x100 y120 w100 Right, 123456
Gui, Add, Text, x100 y140 w100 Right, 123456789
```

Comment: Wow!  That's a quick answer, thank you.  It works perfectly - just the job.

Comment: Sorry to be late in accepting your answer.  I'm just getting used to this forum.